# Group By select

Tags: c#, sql, oracle12c

Tenho uma tabela Funcionario com os campos Nome, Idade, Sexo e Empresa.
E cada funcionário pode ou não estar em mais de uma empresa.

Com isso fiz o seguinte select nessa tabela.

```
select Nome, Empresa from funcionario group by Nome, Empresa
```

Só que obviamente quando tenho um mesmo funcionário para mais de uma empresa, é duplicado o registro, e não queria que isso acontecesse,
sendo assim, fiz uma tratativa no back-end para resolver esse problema pegando apenas um dos registros.

```
var listaFuncionarios = funcionarios.GroupBy(e => e.Nome).Select(e => e.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Pergunta: Como resolver isso na própria query sem precisar alterar o back-end da forma que fiz ?

Comment: A ideia é usar apenas a primeira empresa?

Comment: @LINQ Sim, não pode trazer mais de uma empresa para o funcionário, somente uma, independente de qual empresa seja.

Comment: Seu comando SQL faz exatamente o que você disse que obteve. Se deseja que o Nome apareça uma única vez pode utilizar, por exemplo: `select Nome, MAX(Empresa) from funcionario group by Nome`.

Comment: Tentou usar LISTAGG ? pode ser uma solução de visualização https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score -2):

Sua tabela `funcionario` não está normalizada, porque o campo `nome` pode repetir de valor para diferentes empresas, para o mesmo funcionário,

```
nome                 | empresa
Mário da Silva Sauro | Toaldo Túlio Ltda.
Mário da Silva Sauro | João Falarz Ltda.

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
desnormalização
```

Você pode fazer exatamente o que você fez no LINQ: agrupar por nome e pegar o primeiro registro que coincidir o nome,

```
SELECT f1.nome, f3.empresa
FROM   (SELECT nome
        FROM   funcionario
        GROUP BY nome) f1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT f2.empresa
             FROM funcionario f2
             WHERE f1.nome = f2.nome
             ORDER BY f2.empresa
             OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) f3;
```

O comentário do usuário @anonimo também serve:

```
SELECT nome, MAX(empresa)
FROM funcionario
GROUP BY nome
```

Veja também no fiddle, [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11c436dc0234efec9441199e5fbdf6d6).